# Analyze semantic generality of sentence with python

Tags: python, nlp, nltk, semantics

I'm looking to analyze how specific a statement is. I've checked out packages like NLTK but haven't found anything that seems to fit. I'm looking for something that can give an English sentence a score of how specific or general it is.

An example of a specific sentence:

"The box is green and weighed one pound last week."

And example of a general sentence:

"Red is a color."

Any suggestions or ideas?

Comment: Please provide minimal reproducible sample.

Comment: It would be interesting to know how do you define "specific". Anyway, suggest that you look at [Huggingface](https://huggingface.co/) models. They are very easy to use, and you could start from one of them to build your own pipeline

Comment: Thanks for the comment. A short video about general/specific statements https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=lpBzNsPjaFE